# Property or method is not defined on the instance in v-bind:class but is in data

Tags: vue.js

I have my component:

```
<template>
   <div class="snack-visible" :class="{'snack-danger':!success,  'snack-success':success  }">
      <div>
         <strong>{{message}}</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
   data(){
        return{

            showing: false,
            message:"",
            success:false
        }
    }
//here other methods and created();
}
```

So i have defined variables in data, but it return these errors:

> app.js:11624 [Vue warn]: Property or method "success" is not defined
>   on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare
>   reactive data properties in the data option.
>
> found in
>
> --->  at /var/www/html/carrozzeria/resources/assets/js/components/Snackbar.vue

Comment: What do you see if you replace `{{message}}` with `{{success}}`?

Comment: nothing, I get same error

Comment: But `message` and `showing` work??

Comment: You commented on the answer by Hashemi below, stating "_the error was (I'm a idiot :/ ) that I didn't put tag `</script>`_" - does that mean your problem no longer exists?

Comment: The problem was that I dind't put tag script. Without tag script i hot errore with tag It work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ther problem was that I didn't put tag **< /script>** on end file

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Lack of tag < /script> on end of file, I wrote in my answer but It didn't show because it was interpreted as code

Answer (score 0):

you can check it out by like this :

```
<template>
 <div class="snack-visible" :class="success ? 'snack-success' : 'snack-danger'">
  <div>
     <strong>{{message}}</strong>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data(){
    return{

        showing: false,
        message:"",
        success:false
    }
 }
//here other methods and created();
}
</script>
```

Comment: i copied your code and run it but i didn't found any error

Comment: thankyou, yes i understand, because in reality seems all correct, but I don't understand where I'm wrong. however also with your solutione the problem is not resolved

Comment: I paste my code, the error was (I'm a idiot :/ ) that I didn't put tag </script>